# .header__nav-li_bicycle can't be placed to the right inside a .header_wrapper

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Prerequisites**
It is not possible to place .header_nav-li_bicycle to the right inside a .header_wrapper.

**Expected value**
Place .header__nav-li_bicycle to the right inside a .header_wrapper

**Reproduction procedure**

Run the code bellow, please.

```
        <div class="header__wrapper">
                <img class="header__profile-icon" src="image/logo.svg" alt="プロフィール">
            <nav class="header__nav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="header__nav-li"><a href="" class="header__nav-link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="header__nav-li_bicycle"><a href="" class="header__nav-link_bicycle">Bicycle</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

```
.header {
     /* omitted */
    .header__wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0px 76.1094px;
        margin: 0px 471.5px;
        gap: 30vw;
        img {
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 120px;
            height:40px;
        }
        nav {
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 149.39px;
            ul {
                display: flex;
                .header__nav-li {
                    height: 21px;
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: flex-end;
                    .header__nav-link {
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　/* Omitted */
                    }
                }
                .header__nav-li_bicycle {
                    height: 21px;
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: flex-end;
                    .header__nav-link_bicycle {
                           /* Omitted */
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the right edge?

Comment: @lost_in_magento To the right inside a .header_wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Those Classes

Okay so, after spending 5 minutes to understand what's going on cuz of those lengthy classNames. ***(** Yes, I wrote `ClassNames` on purpose cuz I got a fetish for React. **)***

The pen for the following example: https://codepen.io/devshot-dotcom/pen/wvrPZZm

Now, lemme tell you something, mate, there're some real issues going on here, let's solve them one after the other.

#### The header:-

Why do you need this class, when you can use the HTML `header` element to do the exact same thing? Now the `header` (previously `.header__wrapper`) needs some CSS, here's all you need to vertically align and push the children to opposite edges:

```
header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* Continue with padding or margin or whatever. */
}
```

#### The Image:-

For the image, all you need is the width and height:

```
img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

#### The nav:-

For the `nav`, consider assigning a single rule:

```
nav {
    flex-grow: 1;
    /* Will make it fill the remaining space of the header. */
}
```

#### The list:-

Now, the `ul` needs to replicate the exact styles of the header, i.e To become a flexbox and vertically align its children, hence:

```
nav ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

### Actual Problem:-

To make the `.bicycle` stick to the very right:

```
nav ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between
}
```

To make both of the list items stick to the right:

```
nav ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end
}
```

This will solve (hopefully) all the problems.

#### Tips & Tricks

- When you're using SASS, the BEM naming convention is quite an overkill. Instead, assign a class to the very parent of a block, say `.stick-man` and then nest all the children as they're nested in the HTML, and you'll save yourself a ton of time and headache. (Yes, naming the classes is a headache.)